# Cast Excel Cells

Tags: c#, excel

I want to generate a SQL Script from an Excel Sheet and therefore i need to know the types from all cells.

Therefore i tried to get the type from the cells in the following code with the results afterward in a textbox

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Export
{
    internal class ExcelWorker
    {
        Excel.Application _xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook _xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Range _range;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        private void Show(string value) => MessageBox.Show(value);
        internal void ReadExcelFile(string path, string cell)
        {
            try
            {
                _xlWorkBook = OpenBook(_xlApp, path, false, true, false);
                Excel.Worksheet sheet = _xlWorkBook.Sheets["Sheet1"] as Excel.Worksheet;
                Show(string.Format("Cell {0} \n\n Cell Number Format {1}", cell, sheet.get_Range(cell).NumberFormat));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        private static Excel.Workbook OpenBook(Excel.Application excelInstance, string fileName, bool readOnly, bool editable,
        bool updateLinks)


 {
                Excel.Workbook book = excelInstance.Workbooks.Open(
                    fileName, updateLinks, readOnly,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, editable, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                return book;
          }
    }
}
```

excel sheet: 
[image: excel sheet]
results for each cell:

[image]

Now i'm not sure if that's the only to get the "correct" type to cast the excel cell values to the exact sql type or if there's a better solution i don't know.

Is there a better way to get the type for each cell or should I create a enum or something like this and map each possible cell format ?

Comment: Actually the number format is not the type of the cell. What do you want to do? Only write data to a database coming from an excel sheet?

Comment: Well, you're not going to be able to _cast_ these values to SqlTypes, but you can _infer_ the SqlType from them.

Comment: @MarcelTheis : If maybe cell A2 is a date or datetime I need to check if the already existed colum in the sql table is from the same format and create a "insert into" script when its right

Comment: OK, but if the cell is a datetime, it could be: 12.05.2016 or 05/12/2016 or 12.05.2016:07:00:31 or somewhat else. That is not what you get from numberformat.

Comment: @MarcelTheis and is there a way to get the type and the format ? otherwise i can only be dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: From my point of view there is no way to get the type. You have to try to cast them to the sql types you need for your table. NULL would be an empty cell. Keep this in mind before casting to string or whatever. ToString() will thorw an exception when trying to cast a null value. By the way you also need to cast datetime to the datetime format of your db anyway, as there are plenty of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won´t be able to get the type of a cell. If you want to enter data from an excel sheet into a db, try casting to the needed SQL-type and fromat. Especially for datetime this is mandatory as the datetime format depends on you db settings.
Be carefull with empty cells. You have to check them before casting. In Office 2010 and 2013 empty cells are NULL. You need to check this before using ToString() or something like this, because this would throw an exceeption. Also be cautious with double, e.g. using "," or "." this depends on you settings in Ecxel.